# How can I sort words of variable in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a messy data that consists of a string with 1-3 codes.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2), text = c("3TC ABC DTG", "3TC DTG ABC"))
```

Unfortunately the codes are not written in alphabetical order and I would like them to appear so. Both records should translate to
`3TC ABC DTG`

I tried mocking around with splitting string

```
data[, c("text1", "text2", "text3") := tstrsplit(text, " ", fixed = TRUE)]
```

but cannot find a way to sort and combine these three :/

I also thought about reshaping but then my `dcast` seems to have troubles:

```
data_long <- melt(data, 
                  id.vars = c("ID"),
                  measure.vars =  c("text1", "text2", "text3"), 
                  na.rm = TRUE)

result <- dcast(data,
                ID ~ variable,
                function (x) paste(x, collapse = " "))
```

Any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were very close.. try

```
data[, text_new := unlist( lapply( strsplit( text, " " ), 
                                   function(x) paste0( sort(x), collapse = " "))) ]

   ID        text    text_new
1:  1 3TC ABC DTG 3TC ABC DTG
2:  2 3TC DTG ABC 3TC ABC DTG
```

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel! That deos the trick. The resulting column is of list type though? Is that intended?

Comment: no it's not... just wrap it in `unlist()` :) (see edited answer above)

Comment: Thanks. `as.character` would work too right?

Comment: probably.. you van check using `str( data )` on the result

Comment: Is there a reason you chose `unlist(lapply(.))` instead of `sapply(.)`?

Comment: No, sapply would be perfect here I guess. Completely forgot it.