# How can I sort words and remove duplicates of variable in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553021/how-can-i-sort-words-of-variable-in-r-data-table/), but this time fighting with tidyverse solution of the problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 3), 
               text = c("3TC ABC DTG", "3TC DTG ABC", "DTG 3TC TDF DTG"))
```

I'm trying to coerce text variable to have codes sorted alphabetically and as a bonus remove duplicates.

Sp the first two `ID`s have both `3TC ABC DTG` and third one `3TC DTG TDF`

I was poking around with `str_order` from `stringr` and also splitting into separate words but that creates more mess than good :/

Is there any smarter solution for that?

Comment: what's your expected output in this case?

Comment: If you have a base R method working, why are you looking for a `stringr`-only version? If your only change from your previous question is that you want to remove duplicates (e.g., `"DTG"` in row 3)`, then replace (`sort(x)` with `unique(sort(x))`.

Comment: @Edo mentioned output in the text above. It should be a new column in the tibble.

Comment: @r2evans `data %>% mutate(text2 = unique(sort(text)))` doesnt seem to do much in this case. Am I miissing something?

Comment: is @awaji98 's solution what you are looking for? if not, why?

Comment: radek, using the base R solution in your other question's answer (that just happens to be done within `data.table`, but it's still base R inside of the `[`), replace ***that*** `sort(x)` with `unique(sort(x))`. I fail to see why you can't use the inner-code from [@Wimpel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553113/3358272) and put it inside a `mutate` and call it a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of separate_rows from tidyr and a grouped summarise seems to work:

```
data %>% 
tidyr::separate_rows(text, sep = " ") %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
arrange(text) %>% 
summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: Works twice as fast as @Lennyy solution. COuldnt compre it against base R solution tho :/

Comment: If you want to remove the duplicates as per @Lennyy's solution, you can add `distinct(ID,text)` before the `arrange(text)` line

Answer (score 2):

In `Base R` you can use `tapply()`

**Code**

```
# tapply over ID
tapply(data$text, data$ID, function(x){
  # find the sorted unique values
  sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " "))))
})

# $`1`
# [1] "3TC" "ABC" "DTG"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "3TC" "ABC" "DTG"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "3TC" "DTG" "TDF"
```

**Addition**

As desired output is an additional column to your existing table.

```
merge(data,
# aggregate by ID and then paste to one string 
aggregate(text ~ ID, data, function(x){
  paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))), collapse = " ")
}), by = "ID")

#   ID          text.x      text.y
# 1  1     3TC ABC DTG 3TC ABC DTG
# 2  2     3TC DTG ABC 3TC ABC DTG
# 3  3 DTG 3TC TDF DTG 3TC DTG TDF
```

Comment: Thanks! That would fail in case of multiple records per `ID`?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by multiple  records by `ID` and update your question accordingly.

Comment: There can be more records with `ID` 1 and they can be the same or different. Result should be of the same length as input. I'm sorry for not being clear! Does that help?

Comment: Although it runs with the small example I'm having problem to implement it on larger more complicated data. Using multiple IDs if that helps. Getting error: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = text ~ patient, data = data) : 
  object is not a matrix` and cannot benchmark it aginst other solutions.

Comment: @radek I believe the first problem with multiple records by `ID` should be solved by `paste()`. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you why this error shows up since I dont know what your data looks like if you manage to replicate the error in an example I'll gladly check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>% 
  mutate(text = strsplit(text, " ") %>% map(sort) %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  distinct(text, .keep_all = T)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID text           
  <dbl> <chr>          
1     1 3TC ABC DTG    
2     3 3TC DTG DTG TDF
```

Or do you mean this?:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(text = strsplit(text, " ") %>% map(sort) %>% map(unique) %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = " "))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID text       
  <dbl> <chr>      
1     1 3TC ABC DTG
2     2 3TC ABC DTG
3     3 3TC DTG TDF
```

Comment: Thanks @Lennyy, the latter. Does the job!

Comment: ... but it seems to take double time compared to what @awajii98 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data, "text", " ", "long")[, 
     .(text = paste(unique(sort(text)), collapse=" ")), ID]
#    ID        text
#1:  1 3TC ABC DTG
#2:  2 3TC ABC DTG
#3:  3 3TC DTG TDF
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
    mutate(text = trimws(str_remove_all(text, "(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1)")))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID text       
#  <dbl> <chr>      
#1     1 3TC ABC DTG
#2     2 3TC DTG ABC
#3     3 3TC TDF DTG
```

---

Or use a regex based approach in `base R`

```
data$text <- trimws(gsub("(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\1)", "", data$text, perl = TRUE))
data$text
#[1] "3TC ABC DTG" "3TC DTG ABC" "3TC TDF DTG"
```